# SwiftUI Update text elements

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I would like to update an text element in Swift / SwiftUI on tap gesture event but cannot find a solution which works. I would be thankful for any help.

Here is my Code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct TestView: View {

    var body: some View {
        Text("Text to update")
           .onTapGesture {
              print("Tapped Item!")
              //New String "Updated String"
        }
    }
}

 struct TestView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
     static var previews: some View {
       TestView()
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a `@State` variable for your string:

```
struct TestView: View {
    @State private var text = "Text to update"

    var body: some View {
        Text(text)
            .onTapGesture {
                print("Tapped Item!")
                text = "Updated String"
            }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use an `@State` property to store the text.  Any changes to an `@State` property forces the UI to redraw, so anywhere they are on screen gets updated.

```
@State var textToUpdate: String = "Text to update"

var body: some View {
    Text(textToUpdate)
       .onTapGesture {
        self.textToUpdate = "Updated Text"
    }
}
```